# It is possible to show list/dictionary generator progress in python?

Tags: python, progress, data-generation

I build very big dictionary (2^20 elements) in python using dictionary generator expression (i'm using IDLE for this). The process is very long because of every element needs hard computing. It is possible to get known progress of this operation?

I understand that it is easy to do if don't use generator expressions, but nevertheless this question is interesting I think.

Comment: I don't know how to do this but you can run the task in another thread and show some feedback to user.

Comment: You might be able to get a generator expression to provide feedback for each iteration, but since generators don't know the full scope of the work they will yield until they  have completed (each yielded value is generated just in time, on request, and the sequence isn't even guaranteed to be bounded), there's no real way to give any sort of percentage done without you writing a special-case generator function that has a guaranteed and pre-calculable ending bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `yield` to write a generator function instead of just using a generator statement, you could put logging or some other sort of feedback before every `yield` statement.